# how do I get a token with angular 2 (oauth2)

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0

I have a problem with a service on angular 2, I want to get a token from an apiREST on spring, the server is working, if I make the request with postman it works!, but I don't know how to make the request on angular 2, I have this code on angular 2

```
getToken(login:Login)
{
  let headers = new Headers();
  let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

  // urlSearchParams.append(this.GRANT_TYPE,"client_credentials");
  urlSearchParams.append(this.GRANT_TYPE,"password");
  urlSearchParams.append(this.USERNAME, ""+login.usr);
  urlSearchParams.append(this.PASSWORD, ""+login.pwd);
  urlSearchParams.append("client_id","my-trusted-client");

  //headers.append("Content-Type","application/json");
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  // headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + btoa(plainClientCredentials));
  headers.append("Authorization", "Basic "+ btoa("my-trusted-client:secret"));

  console.log(headers);

  let url = `${this.URL_OAUTH}/${this.GET_TOKEN}`;


  let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

  console.log("Esta es la url: "+url+'?'+body);

  return this.http.post( url, body ,{ headers })
  .map(res => {

  console.log(res);
//  return res;
  let token = res.json() && res.json().access_token;

            if (token) {
                // set token property
                this.token = token;

                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({token: token}));

                // return true to indicate successful login
                return res;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
  }
  ,error => {

       console.log(error.json());
   });
}
```

Server return me an status code 401, I don't know how to build header to send request to oauth2

Comment: I'd recommend looking into `angular2-jwt`. It's one of the best token and auth management libraries I've come across for Angular (2/4) applications.

Comment: How do you inject http?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools and navigate to the Network tab in order to inspect the request. Check it against the backend. With the info you've given us, the error can simply come from a typo in the URI.